# youtube API, get multiple users uploads videos

Tags: json, youtube-api

I try to find in youtube API (jsonp), if I can get in 1 query uploads videos from multiple users.

for 1 users I can use this query string:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/myUsername/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=20'
```

but I need something like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/myUsername+myUsername1+myUsername2/uploads?alt=json ...
```

**myUsername+myUsername1+myUsername2**

or Maybe I can use the search query format :

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json&q=
```

and to use something like :

```
q=from:myUsername1+from:myUsername2
```

Or if exist any another way to grab this info.

I appreciate  any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to ask for multiple users for the list of uploads.  Instead you can trying using the search api and limiting it to only the users you want.

By including @username you can restrict the search to a user name.  Try this link to search for [@youtube @googledevelopers](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=@youtube%20@googledevelopers&oq=@youtube%20@googledevelopers&gs_l=youtube.12...0.0.0.6241.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac.)

You can try this in as part of the query parameter in the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that in a single YouTube Data API query. You can only use a single channel/user as the value for the `author=USER` query parameter, or when specifying the `feeds/api/users/USER` URL.